# Is there any way to set a shortcut for frequently issued commands in Cmder?

Tags: automation, cmder

I use Cmder as my command prompt/console.

I find myself using the same commands many times a day. For example

```
git merge --no-ff my-long-branch-name
```

Is there any way I can store these commands in shortcut keys, like maybe, `CTRL + G`, instead of typing it each time?

Answer (score 9):

Maybe it is a bit late, but still, here's the solution:

1) Open your Cmder folder and go to the config directory;

2) In `\config\` open the file called `aliases` in any text editor;

3) Add this line at the end of the file:

```
my_alias_name=git merge --no-ff $*
```

4) Save the file and restart your Cmder;

5) Now you can type in your Cmder command line something like this:

```
my_alias_name my-long-branch-name
```

That's it :)

PS: Also, some information [here](https://github.com/bliker/cmder/blob/master/README.md) can be useful for you.